# Adding and removing hidden buttons from Wordpress Customizer Tinymce widget editor using javascript API

Tags: javascript, tinymce, theme-customizer

Following Weston Ruter's post here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/23/addition-of-tinymce-to-the-text-widget/

I came up with this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('tinymce-editor-setup', function(event, editor) {
        if (editor.settings.toolbar1 && -1 === editor.settings.toolbar1.indexOf('alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'blockquote')) {
            editor.settings.toolbar1 += ',alignleft ,aligncenter, alignright, blockquote ';               
        }

       //  editor.settings.toolbar1 -= 'numlist';

    });
}
)(jQuery);
```

I am very weak in javascript. This is causing some weird behavior. At first, I got a nicely formatted toolbar. But now it seems to have some kind of override if you have too many toolbar buttons, and I ended up with this:

[image: "Advanced" text widget bar]

All I wanted to do, is add those buttons in the code above, and remove the "numlist" button, so I have just one toolbar bar.

**1) How do I remove buttons using javascript?**

**2) Why is it sometimes going into this "advanced" mode, and sometimes just placing the button on the second toolbar line? Is this a bug?**

[image: 2 Toolbars (no extra "advanced" mode)]